# how to clone a jpa object using persistance

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, persistence

Hi people i have used the following code below

I have a doubt

> entityManager.detach(  )

will this remove the id and persistence only right ?

so i have been trying this code to get the result but all data is getting lost.

```
                Pdata= projDao.findById(id);
                setupdata=Pdata.getdata(); // all data is present
                entityManager.detach(setupdata);  // all data is gone
                projDao.save(setupdata);
```

### requirement

need to clone the jpa object

Comment: In what way do you think "cloning a JPA object" differs from "cloning an object"?

Comment: i believe @Seelenvirtuose  there will be  example `@1f1bc399` reference  for all the JPA objects and these objects  will throw error

Comment: I did not understand your comment.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose when you see in eclipse it gives this reference of a object this way `com.atpl.ival.models.Report.Child@1f1bc399` (this blocks from saving again to db ) this reference will be removed only after creating a new object which i don't want to create

Comment: And in what way does this comment answer the question I made?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose did you understand above comment ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202191/discussion-between-madhu-nair-and-seelenvirtuose).

Comment: was able to solve by this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61478262/spring-boot-create-a-duplication-of-record-from-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detach has nothing to do with cloning.

From the API Doc:

> **void detach(Object entity)**
>
> Remove the given entity from the persistence context, causing a
>   managed entity to become detached.  Unflushed changes made to the
>   entity if any (including removal of the entity),  will not be
>   synchronized to the database.  Entities which previously referenced
>   the detached entity will continue to reference it.

There is no support for cloning in JPA.
You don't need to do anything special for entities to clone. Simply clone it without but exclude the ID.

Comment: was able to solve  by this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61478262/spring-boot-create-a-duplication-of-record-from-mysql