# Spring boot create a duplication of record from mysql

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i have a record of data

entity is given as follows in primary key

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id",unique = true,nullable = false)
    public Long id;
```

what i have tried  and even tried with object mapper which has some other issues

```
Record abc =dao.findById(11);
abc.setId(Null); //not working  
dao.save(abc) //not working
```

> so what i am trying to do is a record with primary key as 1 when saved it should save as a new
>   record ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should create a new object:

```
Record abc =dao.findById(11);
Record def = new Record(abc);
dao.save(def)
```

and in Record class, you should have a constructor like this:

```
public Record(){}
public Record(Record rec){
    this.field1 = rec.field1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating another Object. Clone object by using beanUtils...

Try with this:

```
        Record abc =dao.findById(11);
        Record copyAbc = new Record();
        org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(copyAbc,abc);
        copyAbc.setId(null);
        dao.save(copyAbc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

- Detach your entity from EntityManager
- Set id to null
- Save entity

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

...

em.detach(entity)
```

EDIT : It appear my answer has some issues. Please don't use it, i finally used the accepted answer

Comment: juste 2 hours after posted my answer, i found an issue with this code that appears sometimes. I didn't investigated more and i switched to the accepted answer method.
I let my answer posted here with an edit